New tag request: "8051"
It seems that 8051 architecture still exist and popular.
Perhaps corresponding tag should be created for it?

If you want to ask a question about 8051 architecture, you of course can tag it with "8051"

Problem that tag "8051" not exist. Question is to create it

Good suggestion, this is done.

Little issue i got is that tag "8051" in Search form not searchable. It point me to https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8051
Suggested solution is use tag mcs51 or i8051

You can use this but maybe we can add some synonyms...

P.S. enter "[8051]" in the search box to look for the tag instead of question ID.
